# Silverlight 4, RIA Authentication Service and Roles

Tags: silverlight, authentication, cookies, ria

I use RIA Authentication service in my SL 4 application. I have configured my roleProvider as follows:

```
<roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="CRMRoleProvider" cacheRolesInCookie="true" cookieProtection="All" cookieSlidingExpiration="true" cookieName="MyCookieName" cookieTimeout="900">
```

However, when I do login from my SL app, only the authentication cookie is set via the response. The Roles cookie is not. When I refresh the browser, the response of the LoadUser operation (part of WebContext) sets the roles cookie as well. So, why is not my roles cookie set after I do login?

Answer (score 0):

If I remember well, RIA Services does use custom Role Management in order to make them accessible on the client side without writing any code yourself.

It allows you to do something like this in your SL App:

```
WebContext.Current.User.IsInRole("RoleId")
```

However don't forget to check the role server side too.

Comment: Actually I need to do it only on the server. The problem is that roles are taken from a web service and I want to use that cookie so not every time I need to check user's roles I call that service..